# anagram finder program php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, anagram

i am trying to write a program for anagram finder in php mysql.. i have dictionary in database which has only one field named 'word' and it contains 500000 rows.

by using php i tried to pull words one by one from database.. After getting a word i created 2 for loops which performs character by character comparison..

for example.. let the input word be 'abcdef'..

consider i am fetching the word 'fade' from database..

i am writing a loop and checking whether the word fade is in abcdef .. if yes i am printing the word.. if not, i will fetch next word from database..

i wrote the code.. but i am getting an empty page as output.. pls help..

i have one more question. is there any other way to find the substring of a word without using character by character comparison?

for example : if my input is fedcba.. i sort it as abcdef..
and dictionary word is fade and i sort it as adef.. is thr any function to find whether adef is a substring of abcdef..

Comment: "i wrote the code.." what is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget checking each word in PHP. That's a CPU nightmare!

Add a second column to your table, and have the word spelled out in alphabetical order. For example:

```
Word : AlphaWord
Test : estt
```

Then you can simple run a query like this:

```
select word from table 1 where AlphaWord = (select AlphaWord from table1 where word='$yourWord') order by word asc;
```

Edit: If you didn't want to match words within other words, you could pop a Fulltext search index on the AlphaWord column and then use the [Match()... against()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) syntax which will return the matches very fast. However, as this operator would only allow for a wildcard to be placed on the end of a search string, it won't match `machete->aceehmt` with `ache->aceh`. Having said that, to be honest, you couldn't really add in a wildcard in a normal search either that would match them.

Comment: Beat me to it. Definitely much better if you want the program to respond in milliseconds instead of minutes. Also remember to add the AlphaWord column as an index so the lookup is faster. `ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD INDEX AlphaWord (AlphaWord);`

Comment: consider my word is abcdef.. now the inner query will fetch all the AlphaWord rows which are 'abcdef' and which will be passed to outer query and word will be retrieved.. but the word abcd is also an anagram of abcdef. right? i want to fetch all the words that can be formed from abcdef

Comment: yeah.. as you said, the condition is not matching for aceh in my program. any other approach?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write your own user define function to get sorted string of letters:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_sort_string(arg_word VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp(letter CHAR(1));

    SET @var_counter = 0;
    SET @var_len = LENGTH(arg_word);

    WHILE(@var_counter < @var_len)
    DO
        INSERT INTO temp VALUES (SUBSTRING(arg_word, @var_counter, 1));
        SET @var_counter = @var_counter + 1;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT letter ORDER BY letter SEPARATOR '')
    INTO @var_sort_word
    FROM temp;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp;

    RETURN IFNULL(@var_sort_word, "");
END;
```

Following query will find sorted input word in sorted dictionary word:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dictionary 
WHERE fn_sort_string(input_word) LIKE CONCAT('%',fn_sort_string(word),'%');
```

Comment: Yes, this will result in an array with all possible words that contain your needed sub-string, so you won't need 500000 requests to the db.